# Put a fixed quantity of missing values in a dataset - Azure ML

Tags: python, r, azure, machine-learning, dataset

I'm dealing with Azure ML and my goal is to see what happens if I have a fixed quantity(in percentage) of missing values in my dataset. 
My idea could be: 
Starting from the dataset(take in example Adult dataset) ,duplicate the original dataset and call it  for convention  X. Dataset X will contain randomly missing value in the percentage of the 20%. Once we have the original dataset and the duplicated dataset X we can use a Neural Net algo , create training and test set and then train this neural net with the dataset X in input . What it could be interesting to see is the global error produced. After we can imagine to expand the range of missing values in the dataset X. Starting from 20%,after 40% and so on... I think the hardest part is to duplicate the original dataset and so create the dataset X with this missing values.

In which way I can do it? Using modules in Azure ML or maybe R/Python scripts?

Comment: It is not that hard. Just create a list of random numbers between 1 and the length of your data frame for the number of values that is 20% of the set and save it to a variable. Then use those as your row identifier to substitute the in in a for loop with logic `for (ro in 1:nrow(df)){ if (ro%in% random_list){df$datafield[ro]<-NA}}`

Comment: that is r...by the way. But what you need to do, is learn to script in some language and use logic to replace those values with randomly generated row ids...

Comment: @bethanyP  Thanks for your answer. It works also if I have different column type? I don't know R language and also the concept is not really clear...sorry!

Comment: It could work for any kind of data. You are not generating data, the NA will work in all types of columns. All you are generating is an index for a field. If you are not able to do the programming yourself, you might be able to find someone to do that part for you, either a friend or for hire, but it is completely doable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Sharing my idea, please see the sample code & comments as below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Origin DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4))

# Copy data via flatten data matrix as an array
array = df.values.flatten()

# insert missing data by percent
# Define the percent of missing data
percent = 0.2
size = len(array)
# generate a random list for indexing data which will be assigned NaN
chosen = np.random.choice(size, int(size*percent))
array[chosen] = np.nan

# Create a new DataFrame with missing data
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(array, (6,4)))
```

Hope it helps.